# Which IDE does Google use for C++ and Java development

Tags: java, c++

I am curious which IDE does Google use for C++ and Java development?

Comment: The majority of companies mandate the desktop, including development environment from a mistaken view that developers should be treated the same as call centre monkeys and 17 year old office juniors.

Comment: Right, but I'd bet that Google is an exception here.  Companies that need good software tend to be flexible.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Mehrdad is very correct that it is highly unlikely that they standardize on one IDE for each language. However, there is probably a popular one or two for each language.

A good way to tell is to look at the source code they release that would need an IDE plugin, and see what they support. I notice (regarding Java) Intellij IDEA from JetBrains tends to get early plugin support, but that could just be selection bias (because that is what I use).

Comment: GWT has direct support of creating Eclipse projects so that may be a preference with that single team ...

Comment: And Java for GAE comes with an Eclipse plugin. But that might not mean they prefer Eclipse, just that they reckon emacs and vi users will do their own thing anyway ;-)

Comment: If you listen to the Java Posse, you'll learn that Tor(who moved from Oracle to Google) is getting up to speed on Eclipse, which is the Java IDE most there uses. (i.e. he's not using Netbeans even though he was developing Netbeans at Sun/Oracle and still preferse Netbeans)

Answer (score 21):

Google is not a single person. Probably lots of IDEs and tools are used there.

Comment: -1. Judged as an answer, this contributes nothing to the actual question, which is quite answerable.  There's wisdom here but it belongs as a comment to the question.

Comment: @BobStein-VisiBone Thanks for your feedback on this closed question. I wonder if we had the wisdom back in 2009, when this answer was posted, Stack Overflow would have had the chance to become what it has become, but thanks.

Comment: Appreciate your polite wording, @MehrdadAfshari. I've read the comment multiple times and still unsure what you're saying.  Do you mean this ancient answer warrants less criticism because StackOverflow turned out so awesome?

Comment: @BobStein-VisiBone Comments were a relatively recent addition to Stack Overflow. It did not even have commenting from day 1. Also, I agree that the modern day Stack Overflow should not admit this question in the first place. I wonder if were that heavy-handed in shooting down "off-topic" questions or comments-not-answers early on in Stack Overflow lifetime, people would still be willing to come and participate in the community.

With all that, this would be the exact answer I would give to this question today, having been at Google, with the exception of the word "probably".

Comment: Evidently StackOverflow had comments on May 4 '09.  A useful answer might include your first-hand observations as to which Java IDE's were in use there and roughly what proportions.  As is, this answer contains only platitudes, even without the "probably".  I'd vote to reopen if I had the numbers; the question is useful and answerable.

Comment: Yeah, so not cool, even in 2023, @MehrdadAfshari.

Answer (score 18):

Developers in Google are allowed to pick whatever IDE they feel most comfortable in.  They are even allowed to pick which OS they feel most comfortable in.  So it ranges from anything from Vi to Emacs to NetBeans to Eclipse to Visual Studio.

Comment: I refuse to believe anyone voluntarily picks Netbeans for anything. :)

Comment: I like Netbeans a lot.

Comment: @cletus: if you can't bring yourself to spend money for IDEA (and therefore you don't even know how good it is), NetBeans is the next best thing available.

Comment: @mmyers: I'm a .NET guy but having seen Eclipse and NetBeans just for fun, I think Eclipse is much more suited for serious development, ain't it? I'm not a Java dev though...

Comment: NetBeans is good because it always supports the latest Java frameworks, before the rest catch up, such as JavaFX.

Comment: Just curious do you have a link to that information?

Comment: Actually, Googlers aren't allowed to choose what OS they want -- Windows is banned.

Comment: @Jonathan that may be what they tell everybody, but developers like Jon Skeet work on the C# SDK and other .NET projects in good, and VS runs on Windows only, so obviously Windows isn't completely banned.

Comment: @Nick Correct, but if I'm not mistaken, you have to get special permission from the CIO so must people don't bother.

Comment: @Jonathan I don't know if that is true or not, I don't work there and I haven't seen a policy on it either. If you work there I will take your word for it, but if you are just going on speculation based on a 2 year old blog post, I wouldn't put much faith in it.

Answer (score 8):

C++ people at Google work primarily on Linux. My understanding is that they tend to use command line tools and emacs as a matter of pride. That being said, more and more Linux users are making the transition to Eclipse now that the CDT is maturing.

As for Java programming, I think Eclipse is fairly standard.

Answer (score 3):

Most popular editors include eclipse, vim and emacs.

Answer (score 1):

I believe people there can choose any they like. And maybe most of them do not use IDE at all :)

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking Eclipse IDE has a lot of support for Android and other API/SDK's using plugins, ARM for example use it as the basis for their IDE's that they push to customers (RealView and DS-5). Google will likely push Eclipse as their in-house IDE based on their Android support, but as has already been said, developers will probably be allowed to move away from this should they wish.